# Cannot load http://localhost/phptest:8080/

Tags: windows, apache, localhost

I decided to learn HTML so I installed apache on windows vista. Everything seems to work fine; when I go to http://localhost:8080 the sample webpage installed by apache shows. Apache is configured at port 8080.

So far so good. Since my DocumentRoot is c:\pub, I made another folder inside, e.g., c:\pub\test. What I'm trying to figure out is why the page at http://localhost/test:8080 cannot load? It has index.html and apache is working fine.

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are specifying port in the wrong location. The format is:

```
protocol://domain:port/path
```

So, try:

```
http://localhost:8080/test
```

Answer (score 1):

The port goes right after the host: `http://localhost:8080/test`

Comment: Interesting. I'll admit that this is not the first time I got a downvote for a correct answer, but it is the first time I've gotten a downvote for an *obviously* correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

try http://localhost:8080/test